# Where is the FallbackRoute attribute defined in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack

Here is a potentially simple question that I can seem to find the answer to:

In which namespace is the fallback route attribute defined in ServiceStack?  The wiki shows the following example, but the ServiceHost namespace (where the Route attribute is defined) does not have a definition for a fallback.

```
[FallbackRoute("/{Path}")]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my answer ... the FallbackRoute attribute was added recently (mid-July) and a git pull to my local build fixed the "problem".

> *Add support for specifying a FallbackRoute, lowest precedence behind …
>   …normal routes, static files or catch-all handlers*
>
> https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/78ff21a808f6fb0973f7e2f7a7951820ebae2e0b

Kudos to mythz